# Smart switch for accessing Ethernet cameras

Tags: ethernet

I'm wondering whether something exists - preferably something already available commercially, or which could be manufactured in quantities of 2-50 without excessive up-front investment - that could do the following...

I'm looking for a device which would enable me to run two GigE cameras from a single IP address. Only one camera would need to be sending data at any one time. The ideal arrangement would to plug an ethernet cable into one side of the device and the two cameras into the other side.

The device wouldn't need any significant processing power, but would need to be 'smart' to the extent that it could be assigned a static IP address or accept an address from a DHCP server; thereafter, data sent to one designated port at that address would be routed to one camera, whilst data sent to another designated port would be routed to the other camera. Likewise, data sent from the cameras would appear to come from the device's IP address, but from different ports according to which camera sent the data.

The internal 'network' (i.e the connections between the cameras and the device) could be either DHCP or static - it wouldn't matter, since the cameras could be configured for either, but I'd prefer the cameras' individual IP addresses not to show up on the main network's list of clients.

Is all of this possible, or am I just daydreaming?

Comment: This is off-topic here. Might try superuser or serverfault, although all Stackexchange sites disallow pure shopping questions.

Comment: I don't agree that it's off-topic, since this is in the context of building an emdedded device; one of the cameras will have an AVR-based microcontroller board of in-house manufacture connected to its serial output. Maybe I should have made that clearer.

Comment: The device you are looking for is called a NAT router with static port forwarding. Any home router will do the job.

Comment: Aha! That's exactly what I needed to know. Thank you; if your comment was in the form of an answer I'd accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any NAT router with static port forwarding will do.

Comment: For some reason the system won't let me tick the "answered" box, perhaps because the question's been closed as 'off topic'. I still don't agree it is, because this is part of an embedded system design and my next task is to find an OEM router board or some components to build one, since a home router or office router isn't suitable due to form-factor and port orientation. Anyway, thanks again for your help.

Comment: You would have to ask something about an embeddable / oem nat router.

Comment: I would look for a router you can flash with openwrt that'd give you the most flexability

Comment: While a "home router" is what you are looking for you need to make sure you get the right one. You want one with ethernet on the WAN side rather than one with a built in DSL modem. You may also need to check on the performance, older models may struggle with high speed communications even if they have gigabit ports.